# Spring boot external properties not working for boot 2.0.0.RELEASE with spring batch inside

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm working on spring boot app that contains only one batch job, here is my pom.xml for the batch project (note that this is part of the multi module project)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parentPOM</artifactId>
        <groupId>groupiD</groupId>
        <version>VERSION</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>BATCH_PROJECT</artifactId>

    <properties>
<!--        <spring-boot.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version> taken from parent pom-->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <spring-batch.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring-batch.version>
        <spring.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <ibm-mq-spring-jms-stater.version>2.2.0</ibm-mq-spring-jms-stater.version>
        <jackson.version>2.10.1</jackson.version>
        <mockito-core.version>3.1.0</mockito-core.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.30</slf4j-log4j12.version>
        <guava.version>28.0-jre</guava.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>INTERNAL_CODE</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${ibm-mq-spring-jms-stater.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>${db2jcc4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

After building the project i'm trying to run it with

`java -jar my_app.jar --spring.config.location=file:./prop.properties --spring.config.name=prop`

Which is not working my job is failing to pickup the properties defined that (code inside `@Value` not resolved)

Insinde of configuration class in the code i have `static` `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` (maybe that it somehow relevant, but I doubt it..)

I am using windows 10, tried to execute from different shells (cmd and git bash)

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `spring.profiles=batch` line inside property file somehow breaks that file resolution, commenting it out fixed the issue.

UPDATE

Actually, that was a typo :\